# Using reactive extensions how I can create a dynamic list with values who can expire

Tags: c#, system.reactive

**Scenario**

I'm receiving differents notification ids every 100 ms (Source1) and I need to do put every id in a Cache with the specific received date, if the id came twice I only update the date.  After that I need to search information for the ids invoking a service, when I receive that information on my app, I need to show it ordered by the received date, updating the screen every 5 seconds. If any id is not refreshed in the range of 10 seconds by the Source1, it needs to change of state to display it in a different category or state

**Problem**

I'm trying to use Reactive Extensions to solve this problem, but I'm not sure if it's the correct technology because:

- I don't know where I should have the cache and how to manage those states
- How is the best way to manage the concurrency in general to invoke the external service in the meantime I can receive more ids could be new or old

At the end to have clean list as a result of information where I can see which elements are being updated and which of them not.

Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: This sounds like a perfect job for Rx. You really should show some code - at the very least what do the notifications look like and what data structure you need to maintain the notification for display. Ideally you should have a go yourself and see what you can do and then post that code too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the `.Scan` operator might meet your needs.

Try this:

```
var source = new Subject<int>();

var query =
    source
        .Scan(new Dictionary<int, DateTime>(), (a, x) =>
        {
            a[x] = DateTime.Now;
            return new Dictionary<int, DateTime>(a);
        })
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Value));
```

You can test this with the following code:

```
var values = new [] { 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1 };

Observable
    .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0))
    .Take(values.Length)
    .Select(x => values[x])
    .Subscribe(source);
```

I get:

[image: output]

It's better though to use `ImmutableDictionary` so then the query looks like this:

```
var query =
    source
        .Scan(
            new Dictionary<int, DateTime>().ToImmutableDictionary(),
            (a, x) => a.SetItem(x, DateTime.Now))
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Value));
```

---

```
var query =
    source
        .Scan(ImmutableDictionary<int, DateTime>.Empty, (a, x) => a.SetItem(x, DateTime.Now))
        .Select(x => Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5.0)).Select(y => x).StartWith(x))
        .Switch()
        .Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Value));
```

Try this query - it continues to produce values when your source does, but every 5 seconds after the latest value to come out it repeats the last item (unless the source produces a value and it then reset the 5 second timer).

Comment: Easier constructor: `ImmutableDictionary<int, DateTime>.Empty`

Comment: Thanks for you answer it was very helpful, though I'm trying to get all the dictionary every 5 seconds when any data is coming and I don't know if my way is the best way to accomplish that. I tried using this: 
`var intervalTimer = Observable.Return(-1).Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)).Repeat();`
 and then doing merge like this:
 `source.Merge(intervalTimer)
                    .Scan(ImmutableDictionary<int, DateTime>.Empty, (a, x) => a.SetItem(x, DateTime.Now))`

Comment: @Ivan - Can you please explain what you mean by "all the dictionary every 5 seconds when any data is coming"? It's not clear to me what you're saying.

Comment: Sorry, let me explain myself better. I need to have a notification every time when I receive an event of data or 5 seconds happen without data. For that reason I'm using the merge with the interval timer. The problem is sometimes I'm having the events of data and the events generated by timer in the same moment

Comment: @Ivan - I've added a solution that might work for you.

Comment: @Shlomo - The `ImmutableDictionary<int, DateTime>.Empty` worked great. Cheers.

Comment: @Enigmativity it worked perfect, thank you so much. Now I can continue with my project.